# using the qsort() function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, qsort

I'm a student & i looked up this function in a book. It works as it should but i don't quite understand the inner workings of the `sortFunction()` which is passed to the `qsort()` function. If some one could explain it in detail, please do. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//form of sort function required by qsort()
int sortFunction(const void *intOne,const void *intTwo);

const int tableSize = 10;

int main()
{
    int i, table[tableSize];

    //fill the table with values
    for(i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter value " << (i + 1) << " : ";
        cin >> table[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";

    //sort values
    qsort((void*)table, tableSize, sizeof(table[0]), sortFunction);

    //print the results
    for(i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
    {
        cout << "Value " << (i + 1) << " : " << table[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nDone\n";

    return 0;
}

int sortFunction(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int intOne = *((int*)a);
    int intTwo = *((int*)b);

    if (intOne < intTwo)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (intOne == intTwo)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;    
}
```

Comment: `qsort` is a C function. C++ offers the far superior `std::sort` which you should use instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the actual call to `qsort`...

```
qsort((void*)table, tableSize, sizeof table[0], sortFunction);
```

...you'll see it provides:

- a `void*` address and the size (in bytes) of the entire data array to be sorted, then
- the size of one data element in that array, then
- a pointer to the comparison function "sortFunction".

There's no argument passed that allows `qsort` to know what the *type* of the element is - i.e. how the individual bits in any single data element are used to represent some data value - so there's no way `qsort` can meaningfully compare two such elements.  When you supply...

```
int sortFunction(const void *a, const void *b)   
{   
    int intOne = *((int*)a);   
    int intTwo = *((int*)b);
```

...and `qsort` calls it, you're getting two pointers - they're to memory addresses but when `qsort` calls `sortFunction` those `void` pointers still tell you nothing about the data element *type*, as `qsort` has no insight itself to pass along.  The last two lines of code above are where you - the programmer coordinating the `qsort` call - reapply the knowledge you've had all along about what the data element type is: in this case, they're `int`s, so you cast each `void*` to an `int*` (using `(int*)a`), then dereference that `int*` to get the `int` at memory address `a`.  Similarly for `b`.  In doing so, you've recovered the two numbers that were there *as numbers*.  Then, the job of `sortFunction` is to indicate how they should be ordered when sorting finishes.  To indicate that `a` should be first, `sortFunction` can return any negative value (e.g. `-1`); if they're equivalent, `return 0;`, and if `b` should be first, return any positive value (e.g. `1`).  `qsort()` receives that information and uses it to work out how to shuffle the data elements around as it sorts.

FWIW, C lets you express that a bit more succinctly as...

```
return intOne < intTwo ? -1 :
       intOne == intTwo ? 0 :
       1;
```

...or (faster, but relying on boolean comparison results being 0 and 1, which may confuse some programmers reading your code)...

```
return (intOne > intTwo) - (intOne < intTwo);
```

...or, if you're *sure* the following can never be mathematically less than `INT_MIN` (such values wrap around to a big positive number inappropriately)...

```
return intOne - intTwo;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very helpful. I was hoping for a detailed answer like this. Thanks again.

Comment: I like the way you detailed the restriction of the code in the last line. :)

Answer (score 4):

`sortFunction` isn't actually doing the sorting, it is being used as a comparison function to determine whether one element should precede another in the sorted list.

Answer (score 3):

What you called 'sortFunction' is normally called a comparator.  It basically tells the generic sort code in `qsort()` whether two elements in the array being sorted compare equal (0), or whether the first argument sorts before the second (<0) or the first argument sorts after the second (>0).

With that information, plus the size of each row, plus the number of rows in the array and the start of the array, the `qsort()` function can order the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/), qsort function takes a comparator as it's last parameter.  This function is used to actually compare parameters (tell which one should go first in a sorted array).

Comment: The comparator must return a tri-state value (negative, zero, positive), but the comparisons you refer to return a boolean.  They should not be used with `qsort()`, therefore.

Comment: Man, I suck.  Of course they can be only used with sort, thanks for pointing it out!